# How do I embed my icons, and resource files into my EXE while using Visual Studio 2012 and C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, exe

I have created a C# WinForm app.

I would like a single EXE file instead of

```
appname.exe
Resource\file1.ext
Resource\file2.ext
Resource\file3.ext
```

How can I embed my resources into my exe and how will my code change?

One line of code is

```
Help.ShowHelp(this, "Resources\\help.chm");
```

The other files I have are text files with values for the "About" window.

Comment: I looked at that @PaulSasik but it's not the solution. The solution posted doesn't work.

Comment: Help files like that are displayed by another program, hh.exe.  It is ancient, written long before .NET came around and has a very primitive api.  It doesn't know beans about embedded resources.  It therefore requires a separate file on disk.  A good way to embed such a file so you'll still have a single executable is to create a program called setup.exe, you probably know it.

Comment: @CocoaDev: The answer is in there. Just include your files in the project and set file's Action property to EmbeddedResource. Rebuild and the it will get embedded. Use this method to get to the resource at runtime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx

Comment: @CocoaDev: Try this tutorial: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: @PaulSasik I am aware about the tutorial and it doesn't compile all the resources into a single EXE. It builds a resource folder.

Comment: @CocoaDev: What you see is the project creating a resource folder. Look in your output directory and you will not see it (if you set your property to EmbeddedResource.) And to prove that the dang resource is in the assembly open it with Reflector, or DotPeek or some other assembly viewer and see for yourself.